# When combo box is selected then display Combo Box and then when any Item in Combo Box is selected then make JTextField visible

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, combobox

I am having trouble with my code. What i'm trying to do is:
1. Create a Check Box, make it visible 
2. When Check Box is selected display Combo Box, which will have few items for example ("1","2") 
3. When 1 is selected from Combo Box then make 1 Text Field visible 
4. When 2 is selected from Combo Box then make 2 Text Field's visible

What I am able to do is when Check Box is clicked, it displays the Combo Box with the items. 
I am not able provide functionality to the items in the Combo Box, such as when Item1 is clicked then make 1 Text Field visible. 
Please help needed.

My Code:

public void replacement_used(){

```
    no_of_part_used_label.setVisible(false);
    no_part_used_list.setVisible(false);
    part_no_one_label.setVisible(false);
    part_no_one_field.setVisible(false);
    part_no_two_label.setVisible(false);
    part_no_two_field.setVisible(false);
    part_no_three_label.setVisible(false);
    part_no_three_field.setVisible(false);
    part_no_four_label.setVisible(false);
    part_no_four_field.setVisible(false);
    part_no_five_label.setVisible(false);
    part_no_five_field.setVisible(false);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    replacement_part_check_box.addItemListener(handler);

}
```

private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener{

```
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){

        if (replacement_part_check_box.isSelected()){                
            no_of_part_used_label.setVisible(true);
            no_part_used_list.setVisible(true);  

        }

        x();
    }

}
```

public void x(){

```
    System.out.println("Start of x fucntion");

    if( no_part_used_list.getSelectedItem().equals("1") ){
        System.out.println("It is 1");
        part_no_one_label.setVisible(true);
        part_no_one_field.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well All you need to do is to add an ActionListener to your ComboBox.
May be first you should go through this link so that you can understand the basics of using combobox in swing  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html
Also you need to learn coding conventions so that your code could become more readable and understandable.